# JAVA IO : getAbsolutePath()

Tags: java-io

when i create a new dynamic web project and execute the code below :

```
File file = new File("");
String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
System.out.println(path);
```

*I get this result:*

**C:\Users\Toshiba\workspace\Projet .**

which is good!!!.
But when i import another project and execute the same code ,i get this :

**D:\Eclipse .**

(the path of eclipse's application ).

and that!! i can't explain or fix.

Any help.!

Comment: well, your grammar is bad, to be honest. but why would someone do what you're doing? why do you create File("") ? The Java API says: "Creates a new File instance by converting the given pathname string into an abstract pathname. If the given string is the empty string, then the result is the empty abstract pathname." Whatever that means.

Comment: You are in a different working directory each time so you get a different result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it take **default location of your project** ( working directory )when you pass nothing in **new File("")**.

I have uploaded image so you can understand easily :
[image]

Suppose your workspace path is : **c:/test/myworkspace**

you configure working directory as above ( in image )

and then run 
you get some thing like this : **c:/test/myworkspace/TestJquery**

Comment: please publish this solution so that i can mark it as solved . Solved!!!. go to Run --> Run Configurations... --> choose type of your project on the left --> select arguments tab on the right --> Working directory --> other: type(${workspace_loc:project_name}) .

Comment: i have 2 project in my workspace when i test your code in both it display project name. i have also try using other project name as you have said means (${workspace_loc:project_name})-> here whatever project name is specified that will display.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked the documentation of the method?

> If this abstract pathname is already absolute, then the pathname
>   string is simply returned as if by the getPath() method. If this
>   abstract pathname is the empty abstract pathname then the pathname
>   string of the current user directory, which is named by the system
>   property user.dir, is returned. Otherwise this pathname is resolved in
>   a system-dependent way. On UNIX systems, a relative pathname is made
>   absolute by resolving it against the current user directory. On
>   Microsoft Windows systems, a relative pathname is made absolute by
>   resolving it against the current directory of the drive named by the
>   pathname, if any; if not, it is resolved against the current user
>   directory.

this is probably all the information you need...